# How to avoid variable to be persistent across many requests?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have decorator for my views which creates new instance of `SomeClass` and calls original view function with this param.

```
def decorator(orig_func):
    def inner_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        api = SomeClass(request)
        return orig_func(request, api, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that properties (variables) inside `SomeClass` seem to be persistent across many requests - for example when `view_one` is executed it sets some properties inside apu (SomeClass) class. In the second request to `view_two` those properties are still set with values from first request. How I can avoid this? I need simple solution.

---

here is SomeClass:

```
class SomeClass:
    some_variable = None

    def __init__(self,value):
        #self.some_variable = None

    def setVariable(self,value):
        self.some_variable = value

    def getVariable(self):
        return self.some_variable
```

My proble was that when request was executed and the commented line was commented, some_variable was not neccessery `None` - it had the value set during previous request. So I wrote this commented line to "clear" the variable.

Now I have a question - is this safe? Is there a possibility that one request will clear this variable during another request is executed and it will be overriden in this another request to None?

Comment: You are most likely using class attributes rather than instance attributes. We need the definition of `SomeClass` to help you.

Comment: Yes you were right - I had to do some cleanup in __init__() constructor.

Comment: But wait  - I will post my class code here because I am not sure if its gonna work as expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the correct class definition you want.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.some_variable = value

    def setVariable(self,value):
        self.some_variable = value

    def getVariable(self):
        return self.some_variable
```

This will set the attribute on the `instance` rather than on the `class` object.

```
>>> a = SomeClass(5)
>>> a.some_variable # Just as expected
5
>>> b = SomeClass(10)
>>> b.some_variable # This is its own variable
10
>>> b.some_variable = 20 # This won't change 'a'
>>> a.some_variable # Hasn't changed
5
```

I might also want to note that `getters` and `setters` are often not want you want when writing python since you can do `instance.some_variable = 5` without the need of a getter or setter.